# Laravel cual es la función de el documento config.php

Tags: php, laravel, email

He tenido un error y al rastrear un poco la fuente me encontré con un documento en la dirección de mi proyecto laravel:

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

No recuerdo crearlo en algún momento y no lo veo en la configuración inicial de laravel, pero tiene las direcciones de url que toma en cuenta para botones de redirección y otros elementos lo e modificado y mi error se solucionó (al restablecer contraseña mi proyecto envía un correo a una dirección de gmail, yahoo o dependiendo, este tiene un botón de confirmación que redirige a mi host con mi proyecto, pero la dirección estaba mal)

Me siento intranquilo ya que está en una carpeta de cache y no me consta que sea la solución correcta, me podrían explicar de dónde se crea y cuál es la función y si está mal cual es el procedimiento correcto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te recomendaría leer sobre la estructura de archivos de laravel para la versión que estas usando https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este archivo agrupa todos los archivos de configuración de laravel que se encuentran en la carpeta **/config** y se genera con la instrucción **php artisan config:cache**.

Debes modificar los archivos de la carpeta **/config** y no tocar el archivo **bootstrap/cache/config.php**.

Comment: gracias, en este proyecto solo tengo acceso a filezilla y mypyhpadmin sin CPanel y lo que hago es trabajar de manera local y subir las carpetas ....si ya mencione que puede causar problemas T_T creo que ire directo a cambiar todo en /config muchas gracias